# Get functions DDL command

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2

I need to get DDL of every function in my db for versioning purpose. [Here](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#Get_functions.27s_DDL_command) is the query, but it works only for functions in public schema. When I'm trying to use it to get create of functions which exists in public and match schema I get error that subquery returns too many rows.

By checking all values from pg_proc using this query:

```
select * from pg_proc where proname = 'match_group_1_3_2';
```

Only values that changes is pronamespace:

[image]

How to distinguish both (or more) function? How to distinguish them if they are in the same schema but with different arguments? (by overloading)

I need to use native postgres catalog, not ANSI type - due to performance issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are more [system catalog information functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to give you the additional information.
And you can get the schema name from the system table [`pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html):

```sql
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
     , p.proname AS function_name
     , pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)        AS func_def
     , pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) AS func_args
     , pg_get_function_result(p.oid)    AS func_result
FROM   pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE  p.proname ILIKE '%match_group_1_3_2%';
```

This should find functions in *any* schema in the database.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.
- I was exploring information_schema.routines, but no header and no argument part. ha-ha.