# Function which edit other functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, reflection

For example, I want to rename some function and all it's calls from other functions. I would write the function `rename_func(schema_name text, old_func_name text, new_func_name text)`, which must edit other functions.

Where does **PostgreSQL** store the body of functions (using **plpgsql**)? I cann't find such column in system tables.

I just can get all functions with

```
SELECT f.proname, f.prosrc, f.probin   -- trouble: f.prosrc and f.probin are empty
FROM pg_proc f;
```

but I cann't access to their code.

Comment: prosrc has the body

Comment: Are you sure that those functions with empty body are not internal/c language functions? They used to have empty body indicating that Postgres should call internal/c function using the same name as Postgres function. I don't see any reason anyone would want to rename those.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński no, that functions has such name as my functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just couldn't see content of `pg_proc.prosrc`, but it was present. May be, cause is that it contains multiple strings (I used pgAdmin III). I used it in queries and it worked.

Moreover, I found that `pg_get_functiondef(func.oid)` **returns DDL script which I can modify and execute** later to save changes to function.

Thanks to [this answer to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110301/7573844).