# How can I get postgresql local configuration parameter's current value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, optimization, database-administration

I'm practicing with queries optimization (Postgres 13). In particular, tuning **work_mem** parameter.

There's the DB diagram: https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/12/apks02.

I have a sql function **get_passengers_and_flights**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_passengers_and_flights(d timestamptz)
RETURNS TABLE(passenger_name text, flight_no text)
AS $$
  SELECT t.passenger_name, f.flight_no
  FROM tickets t
    JOIN ticket_flights tf ON tf.ticket_no = t.ticket_no
    JOIN flights f ON f.flight_id = tf.flight_id
  WHERE f.scheduled_departure >= date_trunc('month', d)
    AND f.scheduled_departure  < date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month'
  ORDER BY f.scheduled_departure, t.passenger_name;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

And a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM get_passengers_and_flights('2017-06-01') LIMIT 3;
```

By default **workmem** = '4MB', so sorting takes some time. One of the ways to make it better to increase **work_mem** from '4MB' to '32MB' or more. In the latest versions of postgresql we can do it localy (for function, table and etc.):

```
ALTER FUNCTION get_passengers_and_flights SET work_mem = '32MB';
```

So, **quicksort** was chosen and execution time decreased.

But the question is how can I see **work_mem** local value for **get_passengers_and_flights** function?

Obvious way to get **work_mem**'s value is:

`SELECT current_setting('work_mem');`

The output is global value '4MB', so how can I get local '32MB'? I skimmed through system catalogs description and got nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do exactly what you want, but... To force it, rather than set it and check it per connection, edit the value in /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf and restart the postgres server.  Just be careful as this is meant to avoid starving processes.  I believe total RAM = work_mem * concurrent connections.  work_mem is assigned per connection.  I'm not sure exactly how to check for starving processes, but something to learn.

Comment: The question is: see the local value **where**? It's simply visible inside the function body. Or do really want to see properties of the function? (The `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, basically.) Also, in my hands, on Postgres 15, that query uses an `Incremental Sort` with such a small `LIMIT`. You may be barking up the wrong tree to start with, but there is not enough information to make this a proper *performance* question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Comment: I see. I have Postgres 13. At first it gets the whole table as a function result and then fitering it. So I've got no incremetal sort in my case, cos Postgres 13 just can't look into function's result before the very end. Probably it was fixed in Postgres 15...

Comment: To be honest, it's not a performance question. I just gave a problem's context. It's more about setting up Postgres. Anyway, thanks for your opinion, I'll try to be more accurate next time.

Comment: Before changing anything in the configuration, I would start with the query plan, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS). With some proper indexing, this should be lightning fast, even with a small memory setting for work_mem.

Comment: By the way, the biggest issue is LIMIT 3 outside of the function.

Comment: You won't get execution plan for query inside function using explain. Auto_explain is a way. As for the optimization, I just play with local parameters, that's the point) I don't state that it's the best way to optimize the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should give the desired results:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(c.setting, '[^=]+$') AS work_mem
FROM
  pg_proc
  CROSS JOIN unnest(pg_proc.proconfig) c(setting)
WHERE
  oid = 'public.get_passengers_and_flights(timestamptz)'::regprocedure
  AND c.setting LIKE 'work_mem=%';
```

NULL is returned if work_mem has not been locally configured for the function.

Comment: I've revised my answer to address overloaded functions by using `regprocedure` to guarantee that only the intended function's setting is returned. Thanks to Erwin Brandstetter for mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to see properties of the created function, use the dedicated system information function [`pg_get_functiondef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE):

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef('public.get_passengers_and_flights(timestamptz)'::regprocedure);
```

This gets the function OID reliably - assuming it's created in schema `public`:

```
'public.get_passengers_and_flights(timestamptz)'::regprocedure
```

See:

- [DROP FUNCTION without knowing the number/type of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622908/drop-function-without-knowing-the-number-type-of-parameters/7623246#7623246)
- [Get functions DDL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109073/get-functions-ddl-command/17110301#17110301)